# Creating a Git bare repository from an existing SVN working copy to get files to GitHub

Tags: git, svn, github, repository

I'm trying to get a repository uploaded to `GitHub` and from what I have read it's a bit hard to do it via SVN if it's located on your local machine; so I am trying to create a `Git` repos (I believe a *bare repos* is the right method?) from the files within my `SVN` working copy but am unsure how to do it.

I have read that if you create a *bare repos* that you can't *add* to it, you have to *push* to it from your other repos or something - so I'm wondering, can you push to it from your `SVN` working copy or not?

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you really need the bare git repository. If you have access to the svn server - the most straightforward way would be to use the git-svn, something along the way:

```
 git svn clone --stdlayout svn://host/path git-svn-workdir 
 cd git-svn-workdir
 git remote add github <your empty github repository>
 git push --all github
```

Comment: What directory do you need to be in when doing that? The working dir or where you want the Git repos created?

Comment: Normally the parent to your git-svn working directory. In my example, the `git-svn-workdir` will be created by the clone operation, and I do `cd` to it next line. I guess you may do that inside the working directory with dot: `git svn clone <blahblah> .`.

Comment: Ok, I ran that but got this error: `Unknown host: Unknown hostname 'working_dir_name'`. It seemed to create the `.git` directory though.

Comment: looks like you has mistyped the svn command. Please consult the manual for [examples](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html#_basic_examples)

Comment: Looking at the examples it has this: `git svn clone http://svn.example.com/project/trunk` which seems to point to the repository and not the working copy?

Comment: yes, it won't work if you have no access to the svn server. Is it the case? Then the best you can probably do is simply init a new git repository, copy over the files excluding all the `.svn` and push it to github. You don't have the history at your svn working directory.

Comment: No I have access to the server, the WC and the repos are actually both on the same machine, just different drives. So just a little confused about if I should be attempting to clone the WC or the SVN repos and what directory should I be in when doing that, from what you said before, I should be in the WC directory or the parent right?

Comment: 1st. check how can you access your svn repo using `svn info`. You may use the same svn url as your WC is using. If it is local, you will most probably have something like `svn info file:///volume/svn_repo`. 2nd, you may use this svn url to get git-svn clone. It doesn't matter from where you do the git-svn clone as long as you can access it via svn protocol (check `svn info`)

Comment: Ok, I did that and got all the info. My only other question then is how does it decide where to put the git data then? Wouldn't it place it within the folder you are currently in?

Comment: did you try to read docs or follow the examples? it is clearly stated there.